# gulp-notify: [IMAGES] Error: File not found with singular glob

Tags: javascript, gulp

When i tried to add images.js i get this problem below.The picture is converted successful

```
Barcelona@DESKTOP-DJ763J5 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/Filancer_gulp
$ gulp.
[21:33:06] gulp-notify: [IMAGES] Error: File not found with singular glob: C:/Users/Barcelona/Desktop/Filancer_gulp/dist/img/ (if this was purposeful, use `allowEmpty` option)
[gulp-version-number] Output to file: gulp/version.json
[21:33:06] Finished 'html' after 405 ms
[21:33:06] Finished 'copy' after 407 ms
[21:33:06] Finished 'scss' after 407 ms
[21:33:06] asset app.min.js 140 KiB [emitted] (name: main)

webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully
[21:33:06] Finished 'js' after 606 ms
[21:33:12] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
[21:33:12] Finished 'images' after 6.32 s
[21:33:12] Starting 'watcher'...
[21:33:12] Starting 'server'...
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 -----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://10.0.0.106:3000
 -----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://localhost:3001
 -----------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: ./dist/
```

My images.js code is:

```
import webp from "gulp-webp";
import imagemin from "gulp-imagemin";

export const images = () => {
    return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.images)
        .pipe(app.plugins.plumber(
            app.plugins.notify.onError({
                title: "IMAGES",
                message: "Error: <%= error.message %>"
            }))
        )
        .pipe(app.plugins.newer(app.path.build.images))
        .pipe(webp())
        .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
        .pipe(app.gulp.src(app.path.build.images))
        .pipe(app.plugins.newer(app.path.build.images))
        .pipe(imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }],
            interlaced: true,
            optimizationLevel: 3 // 0 to 7
        }))
        .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
        .pipe(app.gulp.src(app.path.src.svg))
        .pipe(app.gulp.dest(app.path.build.images))
        .pipe(app.plugins.browsersync.stream());
}
```

Whats wrong?

I've tried to find the problem in path.js but it was unsuccessful. What should i do?